# The WP home page corrupted after switching to new theme

Tags: sidebar, homepage

We are an office in The university business incubator as one company and in site of the university, our parts have had some problem after switching to [new theme](http://www.hsu.ac.ir/roshd/).

one of Employee of this  university business incubator asked me to help her to fix the site which have had restricted access to site setting so, i have tied to fix it but i see that the new theme don't show some of widgets like search and meta don't shown at sidebars you could see here:

[image]

but it could be shown in new widget like this:

[image]

the [main site](http://wwww.hsu.ac.ir/roshd/) before changing them is like this:

[image]

so i like to know what information is needed like logs and ... to find out why this happened?(i thinks i must have access to the root folder of site to check the them folders and logs maybe like [this site instruction](https://kb.oboxthemes.com/articles/how-to-reinstall-your-theme-to-fix-issues/) but i have not so it could be effective to try fix it, what do you think?)

َUpdate:

According @udit_sharma answer, I have try to deactivate the plugins but i have don't access and get this feedback :

> Your admin is protected. Light wordpress plugin - CipherCoin |Settings
>   | Hide Notice

[image]

So i thinks why the supervisor of the university site don't fix this problem and i don't like to try by restricted access to fix the site problem. (‌i this situation what proverb peoples say at this situation?)

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

You should check by checking deactivating the plugins. Which will tell you which will the for corruption of wordpress

Comment: Thanks @udit_sharma i will try deactivate them but my user is restricted, Also i updated the question.